# PHP for loop displaying items on one line

Tags: php, list, loops

I'm having some problems with a list I am making. I am wanting to echo out the value of a for loop in a dropdown box but when doing so it echos it out all onto one line like so.

[image: example of output]

Heres what my code looks like

```
<select style="width: 183px;" name="timee" id="timee">
<?php
$timee = '';
for ($i = 0; $i <= 24; $i++) {
    if($i <= 0) {
    $timee .= $i;
    }else {
    $timee .= str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
}
?>
<option value="<?php echo $timee; ?>">
    <?php echo $timee; ?>
</option>                                
</select>
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I'm a bit stumped as to what it is... like usual its probably something simple as hell.

Comment: Do you want each value into a different option?

Comment: @Barmar as i said gonna be something proper simple... I was to busy thinking it was my loop but it probably helps if i loop the options as well... thanks for the help lmao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You print all your output after the loop is finished, while what you need to do is print a value per each loop's iteration:

```
<select style="width: 183px;" name="timee" id="timee">
<?php
// make sure to check which values should $timee get
for ($i = 0; $i <= 24; $i++) {
    if ($i <= 0) {
    $timee = $i;
    } else {
    $timee = str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    ?><option value="<?php echo $timee; ?>">
        <?php echo $timee; ?>
    </option><?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: he shouldn't be concatenating to `$timee`.

Comment: @Barmar agree, added a comment for OP to figure out what it should be

Answer (score 0):

If you want each value as a seperate option in a drop-down list :

```
$options = '';
$timee = '';
for ($i = 0; $i <= 24; $i++) {
    if($i <= 0) {
        $timee = $i;
    }else {
        $timee = str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    $options .= '<option value="' . $timee .'">' . $timee . '</option>';    
}

echo '<select style="width: 183px;" name="timee" id="timee">' . $options . '</select>';
```

This method creates the element in list and issues only one `echo` to output. It is ideal to code in this manner as it improves the time it takes for the client to see the server response due to the server processing the information faster than making a bunch of StdOut calls.

Comment: Concatenating to `$timee` will make each option include all the previous ones.

Comment: @Barmar opps.   modifying to clear `$timee` in each iteration.  Thank you

Comment: You don't need to clear it, just assign it normally instead of appending.

Comment: @Barmar - agreed.  I totally missed the `.` in the `.=` portion when rewriting everything else to be pure php with a single stdout.